# How to get URL linked to my textView in android Studio?

Tags: android

```
String url="https://material.io/resources/icons/?style=baseline"
outputString = "<a href='"+url+"'>Click Me</a>";
textView7_hf.setText(Html.fromHtml(outputString));
textView7_hf.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

This has set text `"Click Me"` as text of `textView7_hf` with URL inherent to it.

Now how do I get back my URL from `textView7_hf`

```
String siteUrl = textView7_hf.getText().toString();
```

This gives me `"Click Me"` but I want `"https://material.io/resources/icons/?style=baseline"`

Comment: What does `Log.d("html", Html.fromHtml(outputString));` print?

Comment: It prints `Click Me` string like this: `D/html: Click Me`

Comment: Indeed. So if String siteUrl becomes "Click me" you dont have an url.

Comment: `textView7_hf.setTag(url); String siteUrl = textView7.getTag();`

Comment: it has the the URL, because as I click on "Click Me" it goes to the mentioned site. By the way, I'll try tagging textView and will check. I think that will work.